# Connect to Azure Synapse Spark Pool from outside

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

Is there a possibility to connect to the Azure Synapse Spark pool from "outside". Meaning with Rstudio or Sparksql?

Comment: Yes it’s just a connection string which you can get from the Azure portal, serverless endpoint or something like that.

Comment: i dont want to connect to serverless sql i want to connect to Synapse Spark Pool

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm with you, I misread.  I mean, the common pattern would be to dump out to the lake and read from there.  If you're connecting to the Spark pool that is costing you money all the time it's running, so do your processing there etc and kick out end results to the lake as parquet.  I know Power BI can connect to Data Lake for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, R support isn't available for Synapse yet. So connecting it to Rstudio isn't useful.

> Spark pools in Azure Synapse include the following components that are
> available on the pools by default. Spark Core. Includes Spark Core,
> Spark SQL, GraphX, and MLlib.

As per the above statement from this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-overview#:%7E:text=Spark%20pools%20in%20Azure%20Synapse%20include%20the%20following%20components%20that,SQL%2C%20GraphX%2C%20and%20MLlib.), Spark SQL is already by default available in Azure Synapse. There is no such need to connect to outside.

Apart from all this, you can consider @wBob's inputs shared in comment section based on your requirement.